# ZeroMQ binding in java from Ubuntu 16

Tags: java, zeromq

I am trying to compile and run my first program for ZeroMQ in java. I have successfully installed ZeroMQ and JZMQ using the guide from https://gist.github.com/katopz/8b766a5cb0ca96c816658e9407e83d00 and http://zeromq.org/bindings:java respectively. I also can see the required file in my /usr/local/lib directory. But when I try to run a simple HelloWorld program it's showing the 
    "error: package org.zeromq doesn't exist". 
I am not getting which step did I miss. I also tried to add the classpath using the command
    "export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/lib".
Found no luck though. I think I am making a mistake in this place but can't help myself. Please help me in this regard. The code I am using are following.

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

public class Hwserver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);

    //  Socket to talk to clients
    ZMQ.Socket responder = context.socket(ZMQ.REP);
    responder.bind("tcp://*:5555");

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // Wait for next request from the client
        byte[] request = responder.recv(0);
        System.out.println("Received " + new String (request));

        // Do some 'work'
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        // Send reply back to client
        String reply = "World";
        responder.send(reply.getBytes(), 0);
    }
    responder.close();
    context.term();
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: May be related to permissions. Please paste the output of `ls -la` in (/usr/local/lib)

Comment: Here is the output
total 36936
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root      4096 Oct 19 00:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root      4096 Jul 19  2016 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    708838 Oct 18 22:45 libjzmq.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       995 Oct 18 22:45 libjzmq.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        16 Oct 18 22:45 libjzmq.so -> libjzmq.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        16 Oct 18 22:45 libjzmq.so.0 -> libjzmq.so.0.0.0

Comment: Rest of them


-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    309632 Oct 18 22:45 libjzmq.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  27838442 Oct 18 22:29 libzmq.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       954 Oct 18 22:29 libzmq.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        15 Oct 18 22:29 libzmq.so -> libzmq.so.5.1.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        15 Oct 18 22:29 libzmq.so.5 -> libzmq.so.5.1.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   8924744 Oct 18 22:29 libzmq.so.5.1.2

Comment: By the way, do i need to put the java sample file in a specific folder?

Comment: @Rcordoval, any suggestions? I am really stuck. Please help.